# Как попасть в директорию c файлами python в pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

Использую tinymce редактор, но по умолчанию он ставит автоматически тег `<p></p>`

Что бы убрать это, нужно попасть в js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js

Как из pythonanywhere редактировать этот файл?

Answer (score 0):

Можно зайти в вкладку "Files", там выбрать и изменить любой нужный файл.

Прямая ссылка туда:

> https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/{username}/files/home/{username}/

только юзернейм свой вписать надо :)